# How do I load my html code to a website, without using word press?

Tags: html

I built a website from scratch using html and other code.  I bought a domain and hoasting with dreamhoasting.  I want to load it on my website database but here is my problem:

1. I don't want to use wordpress, I just want to just run the code as I typed it.  Do I need some sort of platform like wordpress to run the files or can I just stick it right in root file in my directory? And how does it work if I update my code?  Do I just have to update the page in the root folder?  And if anyone knows what is the root folder called?  I was looking at my database files and there is one file with my websites name on it with a bunch of Word Press files.  I was thinking of just deleting all the WP files in that file and uploading my code files.  What do you all think?

Comment: you can just put it in the root of your directory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is not at all how you ask a proper question here. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and make yourself acquainted with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

yeah, You can put that code on your website. But if that website has no backend then it will be a static website. You won't be able to add any functionality easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileZilla and of course put it in your root directory. You don't need to use WordPress for this. If you want to know how to use FileZilla you can search it out on YouTube or even it is available on their site.